# Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed error in the Installation of TooN, libCVD, and Gvars3

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-16.04, linear-algebra

I am trying to install TooN, libCVD and Gvars3 for [PTAM](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/tree/master/ptam) . This link shows the recommended installation steps. I started with installing

- freeglut3-dev,
- liblapacke-dev,
- liblapack3,
- libopenblas-base,
- libopenblas-dev

using `sudo apt-get install`.

Then I installed TooN:

```
git clone git@github.com:edrosten/TooN.git
cd TooN/
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Then I tested the TooN installation with `make test` and it passed all of the tests.

```
slice Passed
vector_resize Passed
gauss_jordan Passed
chol_toon Passed
fill Passed
so3 Passed
complex Passed
gr_svd Passed
diagonal_matrix Passed
gaussian_elimination Passed
zeros Passed
swap Passed
initializer_list Passed
initializer_list_fail_1 Passed
initializer_list_fail_2 Passed
sim3 Passed
eigen-sqrt Passed
chol_lapack Passed
sym_eigen Passed
qr Passed
lu Passed
determinant Passed
```

Then I tried to install libCVD.

```
cd ..
git clone git@github.com:edrosten/libcvd.git
cd libcvd/
./configure
```

The output of `./configure` is as follows:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++14... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking if compiler flag -Wall works... yes
checking if compiler flag -Wextra works... yes
checking if compiler flag -pipe works... yes
checking for main in -lpthread... yes
checking if compiler flag -ggdb works... yes
checking if compiler flag -fPIC works... yes

------------------------------------
Checking processor specific features
------------------------------------

checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for MMX support... yes
checking for MMXEXT support... yes
checking for SSE support... yes
checking for SSE2 support... yes
checking for SSE3 support... yes
checking size of void*... 8
checking for inline asm statement... yes
checking assembler supports .type pseudo-op... yes

-----------------------------------------------
Checking for operating system specific features
-----------------------------------------------
checking dc1394/dc1394.h usability... yes
checking dc1394/dc1394.h presence... yes
checking for dc1394/dc1394.h... yes
checking for main in -ldc1394... yes
checking for v4l2... yes

-------------------------------
Checking for optional libraries
-------------------------------
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for glDrawPixels in -lGL... yes
checking GL/glu.h usability... yes
checking GL/glu.h presence... yes
checking for GL/glu.h... yes
checking for gluGetString in -lGLU... yes
checking for TooN... yes
checking libuvc/libuvc.h usability... no
checking libuvc/libuvc.h presence... no
checking for libuvc/libuvc.h... no
checking for uvc_stream_get_frame in -luvc... no
checking png.h usability... yes
checking png.h presence... yes
checking for png.h... yes
checking for png_init_io in -lpng... yes
checking jpeglib.h usability... yes
checking jpeglib.h presence... yes
checking for jpeglib.h... yes
checking for jpeg_destroy_decompress in -ljpeg... yes
checking JPEG read buffer size... 1 (safe reading)
checking tiffio.h usability... yes
checking tiffio.h presence... yes
checking for tiffio.h... yes
checking for TIFFReadRGBAImage in -ltiff... yes
checking for ffmpeg headers... checking for main in -lavutil... yes
checking for avformat_open_input in -lavformat... yes
checking for av_read_frame in -lavformat... yes
checking for avcodec_open2 in -lavcodec... yes
checking for sws_getContext in -lswscale... yes
checking for avdevice_register_all in -lavdevice... no
checking for doxygen... docs

-----------------------------------
Checking for platform compatibility
-----------------------------------
checking whether feenableexcept is declared... yes

--------------------------------
Checking for extra build options
--------------------------------


Options:
inline_asm assembler dc1394v2 v4l2buffer videodisplay toon png jpeg tiff

Missing options for linux-gnu:
ffmpeg libuvc

Dodgy things:



SIMD support:
mmx mmxext sse sse2 sse3

Missing SIMD support for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu:


-g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra -pipe -ggdb -fPIC -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3

-ltiff -ljpeg -lpng -lGLU -lGL -ldc1394 -lpthread -lX11 -lXext
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cvd/config.h
config.status: creating cvd_src/config_internal.h
```

Then I received the following error when I ran `make`

```
g++  -I. -I.  -g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Wextra -pipe -ggdb -fPIC -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3 -c cvd_src/diskbuffer2.cc -o cvd_src/diskbuffer2.o -MMD -MP -MF cvd_src/diskbuffer2.d
In file included from ./cvd/image_ref.h:185:0,
                 from ./cvd/image.h:17,
                 from ./cvd/videoframe.h:13,
                 from ./cvd/localvideoframe.h:18,
                 from ./cvd/localvideobuffer.h:4,
                 from ./cvd/diskbuffer2.h:10,
                 from cvd_src/diskbuffer2.cc:2:
./cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh: In member function ‘constexpr int& CVD::ImageRef::operator[](int)’:
./cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh:194:1: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant-expression
 }
 ^
./cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh: In member function ‘constexpr int CVD::ImageRef::operator[](int) const’:
./cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh:204:1: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant-expression
 }
 ^
Makefile:271: recipe for target 'cvd_src/diskbuffer2.o' failed
make: *** [cvd_src/diskbuffer2.o] Error 1
```

I know that the the master branch of libCVD is now libCVD-2.0 which is in beta and requires C++14. The `./congifure` showed that `g++ supports C++14 features by default... no` is this what the problem is?

I also tried to build using CMAKE:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. 
make
```

and this time I received another error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target CVD
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/cvd_src/bayer.cxx.o
In file included from /home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/image_ref.h:185:0,
                 from /home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/image.h:17,
                 from /home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/image_convert_fwd.h:4,
                 from /home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/colourspace_convert.h:3,
                 from /home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd_src/bayer.cxx:3:
/home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh: In member function ‘constexpr int& CVD::ImageRef::operator[](int)’:
/home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh:194:1: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant-expression
 }
 ^
/home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh: In member function ‘constexpr int CVD::ImageRef::operator[](int) const’:
/home/csgurel/svo_install_overlay_ws/src/libcvd/cvd/internal/image_ref_implementation.hh:204:1: error: expression ‘<throw-expression>’ is not a constant-expression
 }
 ^
CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/cvd_src/bayer.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/cvd_src/bayer.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CVD.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I know it is a long question but I tried to provide as much information as possible to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to the question, it's different solution and maybe it will help someone in the future

[gptam](http://github.com/terzakig/gptam), this project based on PTAM but without the dependencies to TooN, libCVD and Gvars3 instead it using openCV